# Mysqldump within PHP script executed in shell does not work but same mysqldump command works on command line

Tags: php, mysql, command-line-interface, exec

I have a PHP script which is executed as such:

```
exec("php myscript.php > /dev/null &");
```

Within myscript.php I attempt to dump the database as follows for backup:

```
exec("mysqldump -umyaccount -pmypassword --no-tablespaces the_database > backups/the_database.sql", $output);
```

The above command does not function correctly if myscript.php attempts to run it, but if I copy and paste this exact command into the command line interface of my server, it runs exactly as expected.

Edit: There is no error_log generated, $output is empty and no .sql file is generated by the mysqldump command.

I suspect the issue is due to running a script with exec() and then trying to run another exec() within said script; this is the only differentiating factor I can see that explains why the above does not run via myscript.php but will if I cut and paste it into the command line.

Any advice is appreciated!

Edit 2: The solution is to obtain the error by wrapping the command as follows:

```
 exec("(mysqldump -umyaccount -pmypassword --no-tablespaces the_database > backups/the_database.sql) 2>&1", $output, $result);

    var_dump($result);
    echo "<br />";
    var_dump($output);
    echo "<br />";
```

There is now a $return value of (6) and and $output of "directory not found". Problem solved.

I should have realized that exec() does not necessarly run in the script's directory, but instead, most likely runs where php is stored...

Comment: exec won't have the same environment vars as the cli. Try specifying the full path e.g.`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump` - run `which mysqldump` on the command line to get the exact path

Comment: What does it mean that "it does NOT work"? What is in the $output variable? Does file backups/the_database.sql exist? What is the content of this file?

Comment: @MartinOsusky good point, I edited to better describe what NOT working is. Essentially no output, no errors either unfortunately.

Comment: So when you run the "php myscript.php" command directly from the terminal / console, does it work? Is it just a problem with wrapping it into another PHP script?